# Using subset of a structure

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following class:

```
public class CraneModel
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public long? IDType { get; set; }
    public long? IDManufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long? MaxLoad { get; set; }
    public long? MaxSpan { get; set; }
    public long? Speed { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have to independently populate a list of data that is a subset of what I store here. Data structure would look something like this:

```
public class CraneSubModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long? MaxLoad { get; set; }
    public long? MaxSpan { get; set; }
    public long? Speed { get; set; }
}
```

I'm wondering what would be the best approach here. Is it good form to use `CraneModel` and just ignore other variables? Or make a new structure that would hold this data? Some thoughts about either solution.

- If `CraneModel` is used and it has to be altered one day, this
  could lead to having to rework the list as well, perhaps even making
  a new structure for it.
- Using `CraneSubModel` seems redundant since there already exists a
  structure that could hold this exact data and it could become hard to
  maintain (If one day I needed just `Name` and `MaxLoad`, this
  exact situation would arise, and using new structures every time
  would complicate things very fast).

Comment: Make CraneSubModel an interface `ICraneModel` with those properties. Then `CraneModel` can implement it and provide aditonal properties.

Comment: Why dont make the other variables readonly or something like that or just create a free class for them its better for you because its eaiser to use when this project would be a complicated project so you can use it eaisy and i think its not a problem if you create another class for that it brings more storage.

Comment: If only there was some kind of data model that could represent this data set and an associated algebra with a projection operator that could do this simply. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will recommend you use `composite` because it can reduce the coupling of `CraneSubModel` and `CraneModel`.

If someday you modify `CraneSubModel` will not  affect `CraneModel` class directly

```
public class CraneSubModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long? MaxLoad { get; set; }
    public long? MaxSpan { get; set; }
    public long? Speed { get; set; }
}

public class CraneModel
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public long? IDType { get; set; }
    public long? IDManufacturer { get; set; }
    public CraneSubModel subModel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I agree. Prefer [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: I've decided to go with this option as I feel it gives more independence between models than using inheritance in Enigmativity's answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Seems to me that you have this object model (in spite the class name):

```
public class CraneSubModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long? MaxLoad { get; set; }
    public long? MaxSpan { get; set; }
    public long? Speed { get; set; }
}

public class CraneModel : CraneSubModel
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public long? IDType { get; set; }
    public long? IDManufacturer { get; set; }
}
```